# UITableView unrecognized selector sent to instance (which i personally never send)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't understand why this code

```
[self.tableview setDelegate:self];
[self.tableview setDataSource:self.dataSource];

NSFileManager* filemanager= [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSError * error = nil;
NSString* path = @"/Users/luci/Desktop";
_dataSource = [filemanager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
```

gives me 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e445b0'
where dataSource is an NSArray and tableview is a UITableView

Comment: Somewhere you've used an NSArray for a table view data source.

Comment: (A data source is supposed to be a delegate object, just like the table view delegate.  Usually the same object.)

Comment: yes i did contentsOfDirectoryAtPath returns NSArray, but why would this be a problem i used it before except that time i had a iMutable NSArray and this time it returns a mutable one

Comment: It could never have worked as a data source.  The data source object must support the UITableViewDataSource protocol.

Comment: oh damn i did something terrible, sorry for the bother i must be blind or something hot licks is right my bad people :( you can close this

Comment: No biggie.  Just try to learn how to read the messages a little better.  "Unrecognized selector" is telling you that the named method was called using an object of the named class, and the method did not exist there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HitLicks pointed you use `NSMutableArray` as data source for your `UITableView`. This is wrong. The data source object of the `UITableView` must conform to `UITableViewDataSource`.

Documentation of the `UITableViewDataSource` is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource).

There are two methods your data source object must implement: `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

You don't call them in code - they will be called by UITableView on its data source object.

Example:

```
@interface YourController
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *data;
@end

@implementation YourController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> //this is important as it will prevent from compiler's warnings 


 //somewhere in code - probably viewDidLoad
 [self.tableview setDelegate:self];
 [self.tableview setDataSource:self];

 NSFileManager* filemanager= [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
 NSError * error = nil;
 NSString* path = @"/Users/luci/Desktop";
 self.data = [filemanager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   [return self.array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  id object = self.data[indexPath.row];

  //create your cell here
  return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 5):

**The problem is here:**

```
[self.tableview setDataSource:self.dataSource];
```

I think `self.dataSource` is an `NSArray` and it should be `self` again.

The problem is that the `UITableView` calls the selector(method) `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` and that should be implemented by the datasource which should be your `UIViewController` as it is the delegate.

**Possible solution for you is to do:**

```
[self.tableview setDataSource:self];
```

That is if `self` implements `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `self.dataSource` is `NSMutableArray`. It should be an object that implements `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.